# @Test method is not waiting selenium code to complete its execution

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testng

```
package demoActitime;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginActitime {


    private String UN;
    private String Pass;
    private WebElement username;
    private WebElement password;
    private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    private String Url = "http://demo.actitime.com/";
    private String Urlvalid = "http://demo.actitime.com/user/submit_tt.do";
    private String expected = null;
    private String actual = null;

    private String xpathUsername = null;
    private String xpathPassword = null;
    private String xpathLogin = null;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void findElements()
    {



        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(Url);

         xpathUsername = "//input[@id='username']";
         xpathPassword = "//input[@type='password']";
         xpathLogin = "//a[@id='loginButton']/div";
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void doTask()
    {

        System.out.println(expected);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathUsername)).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathPassword)).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathUsername)).sendKeys(UN);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathPassword)).sendKeys(Pass);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLogin)).click();

        actual = driver.getTitle();

        Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
    //  driver.quit();

    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void LoginValidUNInvalidPass()
    {
        this.UN="admin";
        this.Pass="basheer";

        System.out.println("LoginValidUNInvalidPass");
        expected = "actiTIME - Login";
    }
    @Test()
    public void LoginValidUNValidPass()
    {
        this.UN="admin";
        this.Pass="manager";
        System.out.println("LoginValidUNValidPass");
        expected = "actiTIME - Enter Time-Track";

    }

        @Test
        public void LoginInValidUNInvalidPass()
        {
            this.UN="basheer";
            this.Pass="basheer";
            System.out.println("LoginInValidUNInvalidPass");
            expected = "actiTIME - Login";
        }

        @Test
        public void LoginInValidUNValidPass()
        {
            this.UN="basheer";
            this.Pass="manager";
            System.out.println("LoginInValidUNValidPass");
            expected = "actiTIME - Login";
        }





}
```

This is my Updated Code. I have removed the initialization, finding of elements in aftermethod and placed in beforemethod. When i pass valid username and password, @After Method is not waiting for web driver to login, its showing test execution is completed.

Comment: Your code inside findElements() method where you have implicitwait and other stuff is inside @AfterMethod, this does not look right. You will want to have them before.

Comment: @ChandanNayak, i removed the code of initializing the driver, implicitly wait and finding the element from After Method and placed it in BeforeMethod, still its not serving my purpose.

Comment: Please put show code of @BeforeTest/Suite/Method

Comment: Please update your latest code

Answer (score 1):

Try below sample program, it might helps you. I had restructured your code and used @BeforeTest & @AfterTest. Let me know it is working for you or not.

```
package demoActitime;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginActitime {
    //defining all required variables 
    private String UN = "";
    private String Pass = "";
    private WebElement username = null;
    private WebElement password = null;
    private WebElement login = null;
    private WebDriver driver = null;

    private String Url = "http://demo.actitime.com/";
    private String Urlvalid = "http://demo.actitime.com/user/submit_tt.do";
    private String expected = null;
    private String actual = null;

    private String xpathUsername = null;
    private String xpathPassword = null;
    private String xpathLogin = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void findElements()
    {
        //initialising webdriver with url
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(Url);
         //initialising webelements
         xpathUsername = "//input[@id='username']";
         xpathPassword = "//input[@type='password']";
         xpathLogin = "//a[@id='loginButton']/div";

        username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathUsername));
        password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathPassword));
        login = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLogin));
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void doTask()
    {
        System.out.println(expected);
        username.clear();
        password.clear();
    }

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void invalidLogin()
    {
        this.UN="validUser";
        this.Pass="invalidPassword";

        username.sendKeys(UN);
        password.sendKeys(Pass);
        login.click();

        expected = "expected title";

       actual = driver.getTitle();
       Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void validLogin()
    {
        this.UN="validUser";
        this.Pass="validPassword";

        username.sendKeys(UN);
        password.sendKeys(Pass);
        login.click();

        expected = "expected title";

       actual = driver.getTitle();
       Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not working for validLogin, where in the assert starts comparing the title with expected title, even before selenium completes its execution.

Comment: Actually, with the valid credentials, the selenium is not able to log into the account. Where the same credentials is working fine when entered in normal browser.

Comment: It means previous problem is solved, right? Now you are getting some different issue.

Comment: Previously i was able to login, but testNG was not waiting for web driver to complete its execution. where as now, i am not able to login with valid credentials.

Comment: Are you getting any issue while login using Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking login button, its taking time for webpage to change its title. Hence your getting feeling that @afterMethod is not waiting to complete login action.

In case of invalid credentials, after clicking on login button, the webpage title is not changing, and your getting feeling that @after Method is not waiting for login to happen.

Put some 2 seconds wait after clicking on login button and your script will work as expected:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLogin)).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: @NarasingaRao  Instead of waiting you can also wait for an element that you know will be present in the landing page ( which comes after login )  and wait for that element to appear. You shouldn't use explicit waits. You never know how much time it will take to go to landing page, which will depend on different factors.

Comment: @Shamik - Why we should not use explicit waits?. Waiting for an element to be present on particular page, you should use prebuilt **ExpectedConditions** to wait for elements to be present/visible/clickable,etc. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("somexpath")));                                                                                          This is a part of explicit wait.

Comment: @VishalJagtap When i said explicit waits I meant "Thread.sleep(2000);" because your element might come before the 2 seconds of wait you are putting.

And again it might so happen that due to network latency you element might not come at all within the 2 seconds that you have specified in which case it will fail.

Comment: @Shamik, yes, Thread.sleep() is always a bad practice. I just wanted to convey that the script needs to wait for some time.